# Two different methods for sharing data between Android activities

Tags: android-intent, android-activity, bundle

I noticed that sharing data between activities can be performed with 2 methods !

1st Method :

```
 Intent myIntent = new Intent (view.getApplication,myActivity.class);
 myIntent.putExtra("data","value");
```

2nd Method :

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent (view.getApplication,myActivity.class);
Bundle myBundle = new Bundle();
myBundle.putString("data","data");
myIntent.putExtra(myBundle);
```

My question here is what's actually the difference between those 2 methods ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from [Intent.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/content/Intent.java#Intent.putExtra%28java.lang.String,java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) source code, data passed to `Intent` always serialized into `Bundle` object. So difference is `"how your data will be serialized/deserialized"`

```
public Intent putExtra(String name, String value) {
    if (mExtras == null) {
        mExtras = new Bundle();
    }
    mExtras.putString(name, value);
    return this;
}

public Intent putExtra(String name, Bundle value) {
    if (mExtras == null) {
        mExtras = new Bundle();
    }
    mExtras.putBundle(name, value);
    return this;
}
```